# Cant find the text in word document, if the text has field index using vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to find the below text in word 2007

**Buffon{XE "Buffon" } 1997**

I tried in VBA using selection method, it works fine. I did this using range but it doesn’t work. Could anyone please help me?

code using selection method:

```
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.ShowAll = False
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.ShowHiddenText = False

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "Buffon 1997"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
If Selection.Find.Execute Then
    Selection.Range.Font.Bold = True
End If
```

it works fine.

code using word Range method:

```
Dim doc As Document, story As Range, tem As Range
Set doc = ActiveDocument

For Each story In doc.StoryRanges
    Set tem = story.Duplicate
    tem.Find.ClearFormatting
    With tem.Find
        .Text = "Buffon 1997"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .IgnorePunct = True
    End With

    If tem.Find.Execute() Then
        tem.Font.Bold = True
    End If
Next story
```

This code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a similar answer on searching each `story` within **Word** here: [Word Macro to find and replace all in word document with textboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27259393/word-macro-to-find-and-replace-all-in-word-document-with-textboxes/27259448#27259448)

The documentation on how to search each `story` is here: http://word.mvps.org/faqs/customization/ReplaceAnywhere.htm

You should be able to skip the `Set tem = story.Duplicate` line and just skip to `With story.Find`

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response. Your answer tells how to do find in word using vba but my question was how to find the text if the text range contains field index entry(Hidden text).

Comment: Since your first example works using `Selection.Find`, why did you use `story.Duplicate.Find`?  Did you try just `story.Find`?  If so did that work?

Comment: Yes, I tried `story.Find.Text`. But it doesn't work.